# CakePHP JsHelper Breaking Page Transitions in Jquery Mobile

Tags: ajax, cakephp, jquery-mobile, cakephp-2.3

I've been trying to figure out why certain pages of mine weren't working with Jquery Mobile's page transitions when I discovered the following code in my controller is breaking Jquery Mobile:

```
public $components = array(
'RequestHandler');
public $helpers = array('Js');
```

I'm including this in my controller for an ajax function I'm running with JSHelper, but it's more important for me to use Jquery Mobile than JSHelper if it can be avoided. I'd like some help either a.) fixing jquery mobile to work with JS Helper, or b.) writing the following function with Jquery to avoid JSHelper entirely:

```
<?php
$this->Js->get('#BagUserId')->event('change', 
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'bags',
        'action'=>'ajaxload'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#user-info',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true
            )),
        ))
    );
?>
```

**EDIT*********

Based on Sam's answer I came up with the following:

```
$('#BagUserId').change(function(){
        var myData = $('#BagUserId').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'html',
            type: "POST",
            evalScripts: true,
            async: true,
            url: myBaseUrl + 'bags/ajaxload',
            data: myData,
                success: function (data){
                    $('#user-info').html(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                        alert('failure');
                        },
        });
    });
```

For the url to work properly, include this in your default view's head before you load other scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myBaseUrl = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/'); ?>';</script>`
```

This way you can avoid the JsHelper in CakePHP which (for me) was causing page transition errors in all views from my controller. Thanks Sam!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something along the lines of:

```
$('#BagUserId').change(function()){
    $.post('bags/ajaxload', $('#my_form_id').serializeArray());
};
```